# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

Can anybody help me figuring out this cause I don't know where's the problem.
I've tried many times and even search for lots of tutorials still couldn't work at all. Please help me to solve my problems thanks alot.

This is my controllers saved as Home.php

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        // Your own constructor code
   }

 }

  function index(){

  $query = $this->HomeModel->getEmployees();
  $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
  if($query){
   $data['EMPLOYEES'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
 }
?>
```

This is model saved as HomeModel.php

```
<?php
class HomeModel extends Model {

 function HomeModel(){
  parent::Model();
 }

 function getEmployees(){
  $this->db->select("jantina,bangsa,agama");
  $this->db->from('pesakit');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
}
?>
```

This is views saved as index.php

```
<?php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</title>
  <link href="<?= base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div style="width:500px;margin:50px;">
    <h4>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</h4>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <tr><td><strong>Jantina</strong></td><td><strong>Bangsa</strong></td><td><strong>Agama</strong></td></tr>
     <?php foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){?>
     <tr><td><?=$employee->jantina;?></td><td><?=$employee->bangsa;?></td><td><?=$employee->agam;?></td></tr>     
        <?php }?>  
    </table>
   </div> 
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

database.php

```
$active_group = 'main';
$active_record = TRUE;
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE

$db['main']['hostname']='xx.x.xxx.xx';
$db['main']['username']='this server's username';
$db['main']['password'] ='this server's password';
$db['main']['database'] = 'database name';
$db['main']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['main']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['main']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['main']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['main']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['main']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['main']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['main']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['main']['stricton'] = FALSE;
);
```

Help me please, I'm totally a newbie for CI. Thanks alot.

Comment: Is your other controllers are working cool? Or else show your .htaccess

Comment: <IfModule authz_core_module>
 Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
 Deny from all
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a typo in the controller, you have an extra closing brace above the index() function.

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('HomeModel');
        // Your own constructor code
   }


 } <--- THIS IS CLOSING YOUR CONTROLLER CLASS.


  function index(){

  $query = $this->HomeModel->getEmployees();
  $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
  if($query){
   $data['EMPLOYEES'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
 }

} <--- IT NEEDS TO BE DOWN HERE.

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here. Let's start with your Home controller.

- Don't put a `?>` at the end of your files.
- Move your index function into the Home controller class as a method.
- I simplified the code a little, if the `getEmployees()` method returns `null` anyway on failure.
- I'd use the `compact($employees)` function here. It's the same as writing `['employees' => $employees]`.
- Be consistent with naming, don't use all caps. Save all caps for global constants.
- You don't need the `.php` in the `$this->load->view()` first parameter.

...

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('HomeModel');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $employees = $this->HomeModel->getEmployees();
        $this->load->view('index', compact('employees'));
    }
}
```

A lot of the same for the Home Model.

```
<?php

class HomeModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getEmployees()
    {
        $this->db->select('jantina, bangsa, agama');
        $this->db->from('pesakit');
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
}
```

For the index.php page.

- Remove the `<?php` opening tag from the first line of your file.
- I wouldn't recommend using short tags like `<?=`.
- In view files, its better to be explicit with your `foreach`, `if`, `while`, etc blocks by using `foreach (...) : endforeach;`

...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</title>
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="row">
     <div style="width:500px;margin:50px;">
       <h4>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</h4>
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
         <tr><td><strong>Jantina</strong></td><td><strong>Bangsa</strong></td><td><strong>Agama</strong></td></tr>
          <?php foreach ($employees as $employee) : ?>
            <tr><td><?php echo $employee->jantina; ?></td><td><?php echo $employee->bangsa; ?></td><td><?php echo $employee->agam; ?></td></tr>     
          <?php endforeach; ?>  
        </table>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I think `config.php` and `routes.php` look fine.

You've got a syntax error in your `database.php` array formatting. I'd just keep it in the same format as it was originally.

```
<?php

    $active_group = 'main';
    $active_record = true;
    $query_builder = true;

    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = '';
    $db['default']['database'] = '';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = false;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = ENVIRONMENT !== 'production';
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = false;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = true;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = false;

    $db['main']['hostname'] = 'xx.x.xxx.xx';
    $db['main']['username'] = 'this server\'s username';
    $db['main']['password'] = 'this server\'s password';
    $db['main']['database'] = 'database name';
    $db['main']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
    $db['main']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['main']['pconnect'] = true;
    $db['main']['db_debug'] = true;
    $db['main']['cache_on'] = false;
    $db['main']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['main']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['main']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['main']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['main']['autoinit'] = true;
    $db['main']['stricton'] = false;
```

As a side note, read up on [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) and [PSR-2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md) coding standards. Also, please take a look at [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Comment: I got this error message: Class 'Model' not found for HomeModel.php

Comment: Ah, that should be CI_Model.

Comment: Oh you're right, it should be CI_Model. After I changed to CI_Model, it show me this message again 'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_result.php on line 237'

Comment: line 237 return $this->result_id->fetch_object($class_name);

Comment: Try limiting your results by adding something like `$this->db->limit(100);` after `$this->db->from('pesakit');`

Comment: omg it's work! thank you so much! Now I only have to add search function on it

Comment: Look into the `$this->db->like();` method. https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score -1):

REplace(If index is your view page name)

```
$this->load->view('index.php', $data);
```

To

```
$this->load->view('index', $data);
```